# Python 3 translating a string of keys into values into the same line

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, user-input, translation

I have an input string from  user and I want to translate it according to the keys in my dictionary. And I want to write it not line by line:

```
dict{"a":"bla", "b": "gla", "c":cla"}

user_text = input("Write your text: ")
```

If the user writes `acab`, the desired output should be like this:

```
bla cla bla gla
```

So far I either get bla, cla, gla, or it doesn't recognize the key, as there is no such acab, only a or b or c and now I hope you see my problem...

I think I should use loops.

Comment: Would you mind explaining it maybe with a better example or some of the sample code you've written. Can't understand what your final outcome should be (if there is a pattern could you pls state that too)

Comment: I will try, but I do not want to copy the exact exercise, it could spoil all the fun for next students :) However, let's say it is a traslation of a text to cipher code. You know - the one with dots and dashes :) So - you ask user for an input. He writes a text in normal alphabet and we want to get the result in the cipher: User writes "hello", he gets: ....  .  .-..  .-..  ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the elements of a comprehension list as follows:

```
user_text="acab"
d = {"a": "bla", "b": "gla", "c": "cla"}
res = " ".join([d[v] for i,v in enumerate(user_text)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict={"a":"bla", "b": "gla", "c":cla"}
user_text = input("Write your text: ")
s=""
for i in user_text:
      try:
        s+=dict[i]+" "
      except:
        print("such key does not exist")

print("desired output=",s)
```

you can use a `for` loop to access each element of the `user_text` string and add it to a string `s`

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I was not able to make it work for me, I do not know why. However, I solved it as you can see below (after so many hours) in my answer. I appreciate that you used for loop, as it is exactly the thing I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works perfect

```
dict{"a":"bla", "b": "gla", "c":cla"}

dict[" "] = "/"

requested_text = input("Write your text here: ")

for m in requested_text:
    print(morseCode[m], end='  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for text in user_text:
    out = out + " "+ dict.get(text)
print(out.strip())
```